# Issue on exporting semicolon delimited file to SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, ssis

Well, I'm facing an issue on exporting my data to SQL Server as the subject says.
I have a semicolon delimited file, but also I have occurrences when I find semicolon inside the text, for example:

```
ID;DESCRIPTION;VALUE
1;TEXT1;35
2;TEXT;2;45
3;TE;XT3;50
```

So as you can see I have some garbage that I would like to remove, since this is shifting the columns.

I have some ideas, like make a standard count of semicolons, in this case it would be 2 semicolons by line and remove the extra ones.

In my case this is always happening in 1 column specifically the Address column and complement, so i know exactly what the number of the column is.

I cant ask people who dispose this file since the system is an old system and they can't put qualifiers like double quotes or simply change the delimiter.

I know I could do this via script task but I have few knowledge on programming, so I'm trying to look for another manner.

I'd like to say again that this problem is happening on source file so when I configure the flat file connection it already shift the column so I can't make any treatment like derived column or something else. I have to do the changes on the file itself before I load it in SSIS.

I've been looking for some days on any kind of forums and I don't see any similar questions and solutions for this problem, since most of the example files of people who asks, already have qualifiers or something like this, so I really appreciate if you can help me!

Comment: So the first and last semicolon are valid but the ones between are part of the second field and should be imported?

Comment: Is it ***safe*** to **assume** that the numbers at either end won't be cut in "half" but spurious delimiters? If so, I would put the data in a single column in SQL server, and thrn split your data based on the position of the first and final delimiters, and then clean the data in the middle column. Of course, the real answer here is have your source data fixed. Just because it's an old system doesn't mean it can't be changed; and if it can't be changed that means it's not supported anymore (and using an unsupported system is an even worse idea than not fixing it).

Comment: @DanGuzman I have a txt file with over 200 columns, delimited by semicolon.
But in the middle of the text, sometimes, there are semicolons that are part from the text itself, they are not delimiters. But they are considered as delimiters so it's shifting the columns. I'm looking for a way to replace delimiters or something else, so it should not shift columns anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned you have little programming knowledge but a script is only solution that can handle delimiters in fields that are not enclosed. You are fortunate there is only a single problem field as it wouldn't be possible to parse ambiguous delimiters unless you have additional rules to determine where actual fields begin and end.

As long as you are certain there is only one field with embedded delimiters, one method is a data flow source Script component. Below are the steps to create one:

- Add a script component to data flow and select Source for the type
- Add the flat file connection manager to the script properties Connection Managers collection
- Add each field as an output column under the script properties component Input and Outputs
- Edit the script source and replace the template 'CreateOutputRows()' method code with the version code below.

See comments in the script indicating where customizations are needed for your actual file. This version will work with your sample file of 3 fields, with the second field having embedded delimiters.

```
public override void CreateNewOutputRows()
{

    const char FIELD_DEMIMITER = ';';
    ////*** change this to the zero-based index of the problem field
    const int BAD_FIELD_INDEX = 1;

    ////*** change this to the connection added to script componenent connection manager
    var filePath = this.Connections.FlatFileSource.ConnectionString; 

    string record = "";
    using (var inputFile = new System.IO.StreamReader(filePath))
    {
        record = inputFile.ReadLine();
        if(record != null)
        {
            //count header record fields to get expected field count for data records
            var headerFieldCount = record.Split(FIELD_DEMIMITER).Length;
            while (record != null)
            {

                record = inputFile.ReadLine();
                if(record == null)
                {
                    break; //end of file
                }

                var fields = record.Split(FIELD_DEMIMITER);
                var extraFieldCount = fields.Length - headerFieldCount;
                if (extraFieldCount < 0)
                {
                    //raise an error if fewer fields that we expect
                    throw new DataException(string.Format("Invalid record. {0} fields read, {1} fields in header.", fields.Length, headerFieldCount));
                }

                if (extraFieldCount > 0)
                {

                    var newFields = new string[headerFieldCount];
                    //copy preceding good fields
                    for (var i = 0; i < BAD_FIELD_INDEX; ++i)
                    {
                        newFields[i] = fields[i];
                    }

                    //combine segments of bad field into single field
                    var sourceFieldIndex = BAD_FIELD_INDEX;
                    var combinedField = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
                    while (sourceFieldIndex <= extraFieldCount + BAD_FIELD_INDEX)
                    {
                        combinedField.Append(fields[sourceFieldIndex]);
                        if(sourceFieldIndex < extraFieldCount + BAD_FIELD_INDEX)
                        {
                            combinedField.Append(FIELD_DEMIMITER); //add delimiter back to field value
                        }
                        ++sourceFieldIndex;
                    }
                    newFields[BAD_FIELD_INDEX] = combinedField.ToString();

                    //copy subsquent good fields
                    var targetFieldIndex = BAD_FIELD_INDEX + 1;
                    while (sourceFieldIndex < fields.Length)
                    {
                        newFields[targetFieldIndex] = fields[sourceFieldIndex];
                        ++sourceFieldIndex;
                        ++targetFieldIndex;
                    }
                    fields = newFields;
                }

                //create output record and copy fields
                this.Output0Buffer.AddRow();
                //*** change the code below to map source fields to the columns defined as script component output
                Output0Buffer.ID = fields[0];
                Output0Buffer.DESCRIPTION = fields[1];
                Output0Buffer.VALUE = fields[2];

            }
        }

    }

    this.Output0Buffer.SetEndOfRowset();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another thing you can do is import the text file into a single column `(varchar(max))` staging table, and then use TSQL to parse the records and import them to your final destination table.